# Transparent Overlay For Kill-Counter Lagging Game

Tags: c++, windows, mouse

So basically I have this program that makes a transparent overlay for a game so I can make a kill counter. However, when I click on the game with the overlay on, nothing happens. I managed to make it so when you click on it then it sends a message to the game telling it to shoot, however, when I tried the same for moving my characters head it was just laggy and snappy. When I would move my head quickly, my cursor would also fly out of the game window. How can I fix this so when I play the game it would be like its not even there.

I have tried sending the message and setting the window active AND using setcapture. However, none of these worked. I have tried looking at other places but they didn't work either.

```
/* This is my while(true) loop: */
while (TRUE)
        {
            if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
            {
                if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                {
                    break;
                }

                TranslateMessage(&msg); // translates virtual-key messages into character messages
                DispatchMessage(&msg); // dispatches a message to WindowProc
            }

            if (gameProcId == 0)
            {
                gameProcId = GetProcId(L"ac_client.exe");
            }

            if (gameWnd == NULL)
            {
                gameWnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"AssaultCube");
            }

            if ((gameProc == NULL) && (gameProcId != 0))
            {
                gameProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, gameProcId); // opens an existing local process and returns a handle to it
            }

            if (gameProc != NULL)
            {
                if ((!init_ok) || ((loops % 20) == 0))
                {
                    RECT client_rect;
#pragma warning (suppress: 6387)
                    GetClientRect(gameWnd, &client_rect); // gets a windows coordinates, upper-left corner is (0,0)
                    w_res.X = client_rect.right;
                    w_res.Y = client_rect.bottom;

                    RECT bounding_rect;
#pragma warning (suppress: 6387)
                    GetWindowRect(gameWnd, &bounding_rect); // gets dimensions of a window
                    if (!init_ok)
                    {
                        if ((w_pos.X != bounding_rect.left) || (w_pos.Y != bounding_rect.top))
                        {
                            MoveWindow(hWnd, bounding_rect.left, bounding_rect.top,
                                client_rect.right, client_rect.bottom, false);
                            w_pos.X = bounding_rect.left;
                            w_pos.Y = bounding_rect.top;
                        }
                        //SetCursorPos(w_pos.X * 4, w_pos.Y * 4);
                        //ClipCursor(&gameRect);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((bounding_rect.left == 0) && (bounding_rect.top == 0))
                        {
                            MoveWindow(hWnd, bounding_rect.left, bounding_rect.top, // changes both the position and dimension of a window
                                client_rect.right, client_rect.bottom, false);
                        }
                        MoveWindow(hWnd, bounding_rect.left, bounding_rect.top, client_rect.right,
                            client_rect.bottom, false);
                    }
                    init_ok = true;
                }
            }
            if (loops % 10 == 0)
            {
                if (FindWindow(NULL, L"AssaultCube") == NULL)
                {
                    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, NULL, NULL); // calls WindowProc() and sends the message to a window
                }
            }
            loops++;
            if (loops > 100) loops = 0;

            Render();
        }
    }


/* This is my WindowProc() function: */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        PostMessage(gameWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        SendMessage(gameWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        return 0;
    }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You basically posted a run-of-the-mill, do-nothing, window procedure.  I doubt you will get any help with this tiny bit of information.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzieYou're right, sorry. I posted more.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: @IInspectable I am not talking about keyboard input, I am talking about mouse input. The window picks up keyboard input just fine.

Comment: The same principles apply to mouse input. Read [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903) to learn, why your entire approach is destined to fail.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm not using SendInput, the message is only sent once.

Comment: The articles I posted are neither constrained to keyboard input, `PostMessage`, or `SendInput`. You need to digest the information, and extract the fundamental principles. Once you do, you'll understand, why your approach is destined to fail.

Comment: @jacobawesome7 *How can I fix this so when I play the game it would be like its not even there.* -- Honestly, the way to fix this is to first find out *why* the problem exists.  Windows is not a system where you just try things until something works or try things you believe may work.  It is too complex for that type of blind experimentation -- you need to know fully why the problem exists, and then read up (the linked docs by IInspectable are an example) of how or if the problem can be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post enough code to attempt to solve this problem, we don't see your call to CreateWindowEx().

Here is a working solution for a win32 overlay:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

//global forward declerations
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
void cleanUpObjects(HPEN pen);

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    RECT overlayWindowRect;
    RECT gameWindowRect;
    HWND gameWindowHandle;
    gameWindowHandle = FindWindowA(0, "AssaultCube");
    GetWindowRect(gameWindowHandle, &gameWindowRect);

    WNDCLASSEX w;
    w.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    w.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    w.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    w.cbClsExtra = 0;
    w.cbWndExtra = 0;
    w.hInstance = hInstance;
    w.hIcon = NULL;
    w.hCursor = NULL;
    w.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)0;
    w.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    w.lpszClassName = "ClassName";
    w.hIconSm = NULL;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&w))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Could not Register Class", "Window Title", NULL);
        return -1;
    }

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, "ClassName", "Window",
        WS_CAPTION,
        gameWindowRect.left,   //x
        gameWindowRect.top,   // y
        gameWindowRect.right - gameWindowRect.left,   // width
        gameWindowRect.bottom - gameWindowRect.top,   // height
        NULL, NULL,
        hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Call to create window failed", "Win32 Guided tour", NULL);

        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &overlayWindowRect);
    }


    // Remove Borders around window
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~(WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_BORDER));
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & ~(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_EX_STATICEDGE));
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);

    // Make the Background Transparent
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 255, 255), 255, LWA_COLORKEY); // Replaces color white with transparancey
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    HDC myHDC = GetDC(hWnd);

    // Drawing Stuff
    HPEN myPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    HPEN originalPen;
    originalPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(myHDC, myPen);

    //main loop waits for messages
    MSG msg;
    while (true)
    {
        //peekmessage allows for program to do multiple things at once. faster than getmessage()
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            // if msg is quit, quit
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            Rectangle(myHDC, 200, 200, 300, 400);

            ZeroMemory(&gameWindowRect, sizeof(gameWindowRect)); //clear out the struct
            GetWindowRect(gameWindowHandle, &gameWindowRect); // retrieves the games xy and height width and stores in gamewindowrect

            if (gameWindowRect.right != overlayWindowRect.right) // checks if the x coordinates are the same
            {
                ZeroMemory(&gameWindowRect, sizeof(gameWindowRect)); // clear out struct once again
                GetWindowRect(gameWindowHandle, &gameWindowRect); // get the dimensions of the game window again
                MoveWindow(hWnd, gameWindowRect.left, gameWindowRect.top, gameWindowRect.right - gameWindowRect.left, gameWindowRect.bottom - gameWindowRect.top, TRUE);
                // moves window to specific spot
            }
        }
        Sleep(5);
    }
    cleanUpObjects(myPen);
    cleanUpObjects(originalPen);
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

//cleans up objects
void cleanUpObjects(HPEN pen)
{
    DeleteObject(pen);
}
```